# Creating Timer Countdown VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, timer, countdown

i am creating a minigame where when the use clicks a button, it "attacks" the monster causing it to lose 5 hp, displayed using a progressbar. then at the same time the monster also attacks making the player lose hp. but the problem is these events happen at the exact same time, and i would like a 2 second interval between the events. ive been trying to get a timer event to work since this morning, but it just wouldnt work here is my code

```
   Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)           Handles Timer1.Tick

    If Tick = 0 Then
        Timer1.Stop()
        Timer1.Enabled = False
    Else
        Tick -= 1
    End If

End Sub
```

and here is the attack button event

```
    Private Sub btnAttack_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAttack.Click
    PlayerAttacks(mhealth, attack)
    textShiftUp(numlines)
    HPBarsAlter(mhealth, health)
    Tick = 2
    Timer1.Start()

    MonsterAttacks(health, mattack, CritRate)
    HPBarsAlter(mhealth, health)
    MobDeath(mhealth, MobNumber)

    Timer1.Stop()

End Sub
```

please tell me if you need any more information thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, move your monster attack to the timer

```
Private Sub btnAttack_Click(...)
    btnAttack.Enabled = False              ' disable more attacks

    PlayerAttacks(mhealth, attack)
    textShiftUp(numlines)
    HPBarsAlter(mhealth, health)

    MonsterTimer.Interval = 2000
    MonsterTimer.Start()
End Sub


Private Sub MonsterTimer_Tick(...
    ' not sure what the old code was doing

     MonsterTimer.Stop           ' stop the attacks

     MonsterAttacks(health, mattack, CritRate)
     HPBarsAlter(mhealth, health)
     MobDeath(mhealth, MobNumber)

     btnAttack.Enabled = True              ' allow more attacks

End Sub
```

EDIT
Added 2 lines to toggle the ability to attack while waiting.

Comment: hmm this didnt seem to work, i pasted all that but when i clicked the button, it only made the player attack and then nothing happens, the monster dosent react.

Comment: nvm thanks this worked, i accidentaly did public timer1_Tick() and left the brakets empty lol. thank you

Comment: I was just going to add that a straight copy might need some edits for names...click the check if this helped

Comment: one more thing, when i press attack,it waits for 2 seconds, then monster attacks right? but during that 2 seconds the user can spam the attack button, causing themm to attack freely for the duration of tthe 2 seconds. and where is the"thanks  button"